# React / Framer Motion - why are my child elements not staggered?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, framer-motion

I'm building a balance overview within a financial services application. The content is rendered by passing props into a single `<BalanceEntry>` component and then mapping all available entries into the page.

Using Framer Motion, I want to stagger the entry animation of each rendered `<BalanceEntry>` as a child by 0.2 seconds.

```
   <div className="pt-16">
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -20 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 1 }}
        transition={{
          delay: 0.3,
          default: { ease: 'easeInOut' },
          staggerChildren: 0.2,
        }}
      >
        {TransactionData.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <motion.div variants={BalanceEntryVariants}>
                <BalanceEntry
                  transactionDate={item.transactionDate}
                  transactionType={item.transactionType}
                  transactionID={item.transactionID}
                  transactionAmount={item.transactionAmount}
                  transactionIcon={item.transactionIcon}
                />
              </motion.div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </motion.div>
    </div>
          );
```

I have created two motion.divs based on multiple suggestions here on SO to achieve the staggering, but I still fail to have **each** BalanceEntry component animated with staggering, instead they are always animated as a group:

[image]

The variants are setup like this:

```
    const BalanceEntryVariants = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    y: -20,
  },
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    x: 1,
    transition: {
      ease: 'easeInOut',
    },
  },
};
```

Where is my mistake to render each individual BalanceEntry staggered happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this can be solved by defining a variant for the parent `motion.div` as well, perhaps try something like:

```
const parent = {
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    y: -20,
    transition: {
      when: 'beforeChildren',
      staggerChildren: 0.2,
      delay: 0.3,
    },
  },
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    x: 1,
    transition: {
      when: 'afterChildren',
    },
  },
};
```

Add the variant to parent `motion.div`:

```
<motion.div initial="hidden" animate="visible" variants={parent}>
...
</motion.div>
```

Here is a minimized example running on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pu2kpq?file=src/App.js)

There might be other issues as well (not sure about the purpose of `y: -20` and `x: 1`), but hopefully this would still help.

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly - much-appreciated input!