# Text not staggering in Framer Motion text reveal animation

Tags: next.js, next.js13, framer-motion

So I am new to Framer Motion and with the help of some articles I tried to Stagger Text and make a Text Reveal Animation for my portfolio but with every example i could possibly find, I am not able to stagger the individual characters of the sentence and the whole animation occurs simutaneously to all the characters in the sentence.
Also when I set loop for sentence so that i can get individual characters in <motion.span> tag then the y-axis animation that was happening when the sentence was as whole that also doesn't works and only animation works is opacity that too without stagger.

Code:

```
"use client";
import { Variants, motion } from "framer-motion";


const MainHeading = () => {
  const textVariant: Variants = {
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: "80",
    },
    visible: {
      y: 0,
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        ease: "easeInOut",
      },
    },
  };

  const textContainerVariant: Variants = {
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: "80",
    },
    visible: {
      y: 0,
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        staggerChildren: 0.5,
        delayChildren: 0.5,
      },
    },
  };

  const headingLine = "Full Stack Web Dev";

  return (
    <motion.div
      initial="hidden"
      animate="visible"
      variants={textContainerVariant}
      className="text-8xl lg:text-9xl"
    >
      {headingLine.split("").map((char, index) => {
        return (
          <motion.span
            key={char + "-" + index}
            variants={textVariant}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="visible"
            className="inline-block"
            custom={index}
          >
            {char}
          </motion.span>
        );
      })}
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export { MainHeading };
```

[Video of how its happening](https://imgur.com/a/sKE9jfm)

whereas I want text reveal animation with stagger effect
I cannot understand what's wrong in this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React / Framer Motion - why are my child elements not staggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74654059/react-framer-motion-why-are-my-child-elements-not-staggered)

Comment: Already tried, didn't worked

Comment: Okay, I've retracted my close vote then. Good luck.

Comment: I believe this is something related to the motion span or normal span and inline block thing

Answer (score 0):

Finally this solution worked
Same transition properties in both intial and animate
Child Elements should only have variant declared but not the initial and animate properties, those will be taken from parent

### Solution:

```js
"use client";
import { Variants, motion } from "framer-motion";

const MainHeading = () => {
  const heading = "Full Stack Web Dev";
  const letters = Array.from(heading);
  const container: Variants = {
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
    },
    visible: (i = 1) => ({
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        staggerChildren: 0.025,
        delayChildren: 0.025 * i,
      },
    }),
  };

  const child: Variants = {
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: 20,
      transition: {
        type: "spring",
        stiffness: 100,
        damping: 12,
      },
    },
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      y: 0,
      transition: {
        type: "spring",
        stiffness: 100,
        damping: 12,
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      className="overflow-hidden"
      variants={container}
      initial="hidden"
      animate="visible"
    >
      {letters.map((letter, index) => (
        <motion.span className="inline-block" key={index} variants={child}>
          {letter === " " ? "\u00A0" : letter}
        </motion.span>
      ))}
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export { MainHeading };
```

**Dont ask my about the variable i from dynamic animate property, I tried without it, it still worked the same, but still I kept it!